# Interlocked equivalent on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, atomic

In a C++ Linux app, what is the simplest way to get the functionality that the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) functions on Win32 provide?  Specifically, a lightweight way to atomically increment or add 32 or 64 bit integers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upon further review, [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) looks promising.  Yay stack overflow.

Comment: Please don't write link only answers. The key information should be in the answer. Supplement that with a link by all means.

Answer (score 9):

Just few notes to clarify the issue which has nothing to do with *Linux*.

**RWM** (read-modify-write) operations and those that do not execute in a single-step need the hardware-support to execute *atomically*; among them increments and decrements, fetch_and_add, etc.

For some architecture (including I386, AMD_64 and IA64) gcc has a built-in support for atomic memory access, therefore no external libray is required. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) you can read some information about the API.

Answer (score 8):

Intel's open-source [ThreadBuildingBlocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has a template, Atomic, that offers the same functionality as .NET's Interlocked class.

Unlike gcc's Atomic built-ins, it's cross platform and doesn't depend on a particular compiler. As Nemanja Trifunovic correctly points out above, it does depend on the [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_and_swap) CPU instruction provided by x86 and Itanium chips. I guess you wouldn't expect anything else from an Intel library : )

Answer (score 8):

Strictly speaking, Linux cannot offer atomic "interlocked" functions like ones in Win32, simply because these functions require hardware support, and Linux runs on some platforms that don't offer that support. Having said that, if you can constrain yourself to Intel x86/x64, take a look at the implementation of reference counting in Boost shared pointers library.

Answer (score 3):

The [atomic](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__atomic.html) functions from the Apache Portable Runtime are really close to the Win32 InterlockedXXX functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert some assembly code in your source, to use x68 interlocked instructions directly.

You should use a **lock xadd** operation.

See for instance [this](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=17369.0).

Answer (score 2):

The fairly common glib library that's used in GTK and QT programming as well as standalone offers a variety of atomic operations.  See http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.16/glib-Atomic-Operations.html for a list.  There are `g_atomic` functions for most of the operations that Interlocked supports on Win32, and on platforms where the hardware directly supports these, they are inlined as the needed assembly code.