# Equivalent of InterlockedIncrement in Linux/gcc

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, assembly, intrinsics

It would be a very simple question (could be duplicated), but I was unable to find it.

Win32 API provides a very handy set of atomic operations (as intrinsics) such as `InterlockedIncrement` which emits `lock add` x86 code. Also, `InterlockedCompareExchange` is mapped to `lock cmpxchg`.

But, I want to do that in Linux with gcc. Since I'm working 64-bit, it's impossible to use inline assembly. Are there intrinsics for gcc?

Comment: You might want to search on "interlocked increment gcc" or "interlocked increment linux" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149710/interlocked-equivalent-on-linux)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[GCC Atomic Built-ins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins)

Comment: Thanks! `__sync_fetch_and_add` was the one.

Comment: Actually, the equivalent of InterlockedIncrement() would be __sync_add_and_fetch(). __sync_fetch_and_add() returns the previous value, unlike InterlockedIncrement() which returns the new value.