# Can not using a mutex to read shared data result in arbitrarily stale data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Let's say we have this simple class:

```
class example
{
    bool m_isCanceled;
    example() : m_isCanceled(false) {}
public:
    void cancel() { m_isCanceled = true; }

    void doWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; ++i)
        {
            // Slow
            doStuff();

            if (m_isCanceled)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we call `example::doWork()` on one thread, and then, after a while we call `example::cancel()` on another, is there a bound on how long until the first thread will see that `m_isCanceled` is now true?

In a similar situation, I suggested we protect m_isCanceled with a mutex, but my co-worker said that the first thread would see the update after an extra iteration, at most. Is this right?

Comment: No, he's not right – without a memory fence, the first thread may _never_ see the update.

Comment: you should declare `m_isCanceled` as `atomic<bool>` if you are using C++11, or synchronize its access with a mutex if you are not.

Comment: @Andy : Fortunately for those on old toolsets, Boost 1.53 will include the new Boost.Atomic library. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: nice to hear, thank you for sharing the information :)

Comment: You need AT LEAST `volatile` on your `m_isCanceled` - that should stop it from being cached in a register in the loop. However, on some architecturse, that's not enough, since cache's aren't updated when another core writes to the variable - in which case you must use atomic type operations.

Comment: Remark that in Windows, without boost or C++11, you can also use the Interlocked* functions (and in Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149710/interlocked-equivalent-on-linux) to get atomic operations, and as pointed out above, you definitely need to make it volatile to prevent inappropriate optimizations.

Comment: @thang: You don't need `volatile` if you use atomic operations. `volatile` is an ugly hack. Atomic operations is the right way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I think you are probably right in practice.  I can't come up with a possible compiler optimization that would screw up the case with atomic operations.  However, I can't be sure that I've thought of everything.

Comment: @thang: This is precisely what atomic operations are *for*. If a compiler optimization screwed this up, that would mean your atomic operation implementation was broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you're right if the variable is made atomic.  i am thinking of the half and half cases where write/inc are made atomic but when there are no exchanges made, typically it is read directly (and this is really where the problem is).  For example, I think that there is no interlocked compare functions that do not also write (for example, in windows).  So a read (without write) is usually done by directly accessing the variable.  In this case, if the variable is not volatile, it can be made a register.  You're right this is due to faulty implementation.  Volatile prevents this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee at all. Ideally you would make the boolean variable atomic. Failing that, making it `volatile` happens to work on pretty much all known platforms. Of course protecting it with a mutex is guaranteed to work.

In practice, it will "happen to work" anyway. The implementation generally won't know if `doStuff`, or some function it calls, manipulates `m_isCancelled`. So it won't be able to keep it in a register or something across those calls.

Comment: Doesn't your second paragraph presume that `doStuff()` isn't inlineable? [I appreciate it says "slow" on the comment above, which MAY mean complicated and not inlineable].

Comment: It depends exactly what `doStuff` does. It is definitely possible to write code on real-world platforms where the change is never seen.

Comment: doStuff() is actually a method call on a member variable, which does an http request. It passes in a bunch of member variables into the call, but not m_isCanceled.

Comment: @Bwmat: Then it will almost certainly "happen to work". Anything another thread could do, one of those functions could do, unless the implementation can inline that whole thing which, in practice, it can't. However, who knows what a next generation of smarter compilers (or hardware that requires more handholding for thread synchronization) will do. If you have atomic types, use them. If performance isn't critical, use mutexes. Failing that, use `volatile` but consider it a platform-dependent optimization to be used where `volatile` is known to be sufficient.

Comment: In fact, this is a nuisance that is seen in almost all software.  If doStuff() does an http request and waits for the response, then when cancel() is called, the cancel won't happen until after doStuff() is done.  This completely defeats the whole purpose of cancel().  What happens when the network is out and doStuff() hangs until the timeout period expires?  This issue plagues most software!  It destroys usability.

Comment: @thang : That's what asynchronous operations are for. See e.g. [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/).

Comment: @thang: Only if you make the user wait for the cancellation to complete, which I agree would be boneheaded. Leaving a thread doing something you no longer need it to do, so long as it's harmless, to shut down when convenient, is a common and harmless pattern. Who cares how long it continues to fail? What difference does it make so long as nobody is waiting for its results any more?

Comment: @ildjarm, that is exactly right, and it doesn't need to be boost.  In Windows, it's the overlapped operations.  In *ix, it's the variants of the select.  However, in these cases, cancel needs to be tied to the i/o operation.  My previous comment was with respect to the fact that a lot of software packages don't use it properly (e.g. Firefox, for example.  Try it on a slow internet connection).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the problem is that usually when you need to cancel, it is due to a user request, and there are other jobs pending.  I guess the "boneheaded" scenario :p

Comment: @thang: So what? The user asks you to cancel something, and you tell the thread doing it to cancel at its leisure. Why would the user care how long it takes you to shutdown a thread? That's an internal invisible detail. Of course, nothing should be waiting for that thread, but that should *precede* your attempt to cancel the operation. The canonical reason to cancel an operation is that nobody is interested in the result of that operation anymore.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, if the user asks you to cancel loading a website and load a new website, and you're blocking waiting to cancel, then the new website gets stalled.  if you create a new thread to load the new website, then after awhile, you end up with a bunch of extra threads that are sitting around waiting for something to finish.  threads aren't free.

Comment: @thang: You don't block waiting to cancel. The reason you cancel is because you *aren't* going to wait for the results any more. A bunch of extra threads waiting for something to finish due to a manual cancellation are totally irrelevant unless you're talking about some very unusual situations, and there's no reason to think we're in such an odd situation here.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts, if you aren't going to wait for the execution to finish, this means you need a thread per connection.  In a typical browser, the number of connections can go up to hundreds or thousands if you want to parallelize operations.  would you create that many threads to have one per connection?  if you share connections per thread and the thread is blocked due to one connection, what happens to all the others?  remember that threads require more than just the idle execution context.

Comment: @thang: If you're not using a thread per connection, then whatever operation you're wrapping in an `if (!cancelled)` loop will completely fairly immediately no matter what. If you're using a thread per connection, then you have a problem with lots of connections. That has nothing to do with how you implement cancellation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you're right, it has to do with how doStuff(.) is implemented.  this is the original remark in response to the comment that dostuff does http request.  that aside, consider if firefox does this, the user wants to exit and restart, and on exit, it's waiting for a thread to exit after a cancel is issued (can be many seconds or minutes).  the user then can't restart because firefox enforces single process per system.  actually more like single access to datastore, but it has the same effect.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and a second scenario where cancel is called inside the destructor.  if it doesn't wait for the thread to exit (waiting would cause the first sceneario), then what happens?  i realize this is really a bug, but it's always good to have coding practice that minimizes opportunities for bugs.  cancel sets cancelled to true, the destructor exits, and the program continues to de-allocate the object.  half way through doStuff(.), the object is destroyed, what happens?

Comment: @thang: The thread that cancels the event must also have a reference to the event otherwise it couldn't find it to cancel it. The thread that's working on the event must have a reference to it otherwise it couldn't be working on it. So if one thread cancels an event another thread is working on, that cannot trigger destruction. You would never manually call the destructor on an object shared between threads. This is how you do things sanely. ("Don't do things the right way because it's too easy to get the right way wrong", well, I don't agree. The chance of getting it right is worth it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, ah, it seems you misinterpreted my comment.  would love to continue, but I think SO will kick us out quite soon.  We can take this off line if you're interested, but this is a relatively canonical discussion (as in, we've both probably had the exact same discussion before with many other people).